# Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite Changing File Associations not working

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, file-association

On the Mac I've got OS X 10.10 Yosemite and when I right-click and open-with a different program (and have to manually allow programs that *aren't* suggested) OS X immediately ignores me and keeps opening wav/aif files in iTunes instead of the other program.

**How do I force Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite to honor custom file associations?**

Comment: Are you saying that ‘‘open with’’ doesn’t work ***at all**,* and that files are always opened with the hard-coded default program,  or are you saying that, when you do ‘‘open with’’, the system *doesn’t remember your selection* and goes back to using the default program *next time* you do an “Open”?

Answer (score 12):

Doing a right-click "Open With" does not make any persistent change to the file associations (actually, it's called the Launch Services settings in OS X).

What you need to fo is "Get Info" on the file (either from the right-click context menu, or by selecting the file and choosing File > Get Info from the menu bar), changing the setting in the "Open with" section of the Info window, and then clicking "Change All" below that.

Comment: Interestingly, right click + ⌥Option and selecting "Always Open With" _also_ only works for one file.